# not able to alert json data in ajax success call

Tags: angularjs, ajax, codeigniter

I am not able to alert the first name of the user

```
$scope.Edit=function(id){       
    $http.post(  
        "<?php echo BASE_URL;?>Registration/Edit", {id :id}  
        ).then(function(response){
        var myJSON = JSON.stringify(response.data);                 
        alert(myJSON);
        //alert(response.first_name);
        $scope.name = response.first_name;
        name();   //alert(response.id);
    });
}
```

After This function in angular js:

In json response i am getting:

```
{"id":"4","first_name":"Rupal","last_name":"Pant"}
```

> ```
> my php function which return the json value is:
> ```

```
public function Edit(){
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $id=$data->id;
    $query = "select * from tbl_user where id='".$id."'";
    $check = $this->db->query($query);
    $result = $check->row_array();
    //echo $this->db->last_query();
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

The problem is that when i am getting the json response why i am not able to alrt the user name after the edit success response what i am doing wrong here please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first_name is inside `response.data` object. use `response.data.first_name` instead

Comment: Thanx its woring @riyenz

Comment: Welcome. Accept the answer so that others can easily see the answer.